# String insertion

Tags: string, system

I have problems with inserting string variable inside text.

```
string p="http://www.google.com" ;
system("c:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe \"http://www.google.com\"");
```

I need a way to use p instead of "http://www.google.com\" 
I tried

```
  system("c:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe \%p\"");
```

but it doesn't work. I'm not very good with strings so probably that's the prob.

Comment: In what programming language? You haven't tagged it with one or specified in your question.

Comment: There is no magic.  When asking a programming question, consider identifying the language.

Comment: What led you to the conclusion that `\%p` would work? What C++ book are you using? Did you search for "string concatenation C++" on the interwebtubes?

Comment: Nothing, I just thought it might work...I don't learn from books, i explore the language myself and in school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can use the + operator to concatenate strings:

```
system((std::string("c:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe ") + p).data());
```

In this case this is a bit hard to read, so you're better off creating the string before hand.
A better way would be to use stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream sstr;
std::string p = "http://www.google.com";
sstr << "c:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe " << p;
system(sstr.str().data());
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it.. xD

Comment: There should be a tick next to my answer, and under the score (currently 0). If you hover over it it will say "click to set as accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume c#

```
string blammy = @"c:\progra~1\intern~1\iexplore.exe";
string finalAnswer;
string pikaPika = @"http://www.google.com";

finalAnswer = blammy + " " + pikaPika;

system(finalAnswer);
```